# How to repair old zip blind with tears and cracks?

Tags: blinds

Good Afternoon,

Anyway, I  am trying to repair this cracked old zip blind:

https://ibb.co/4JzYGtM

Part of the cracked plastic came off the rail and there are tears.

I'm thinking of glueing those pieces back on the rail, and for the tears I will put strong duct tape behind it.

**I am wondering if this will in any way interfere with the rolling mechanism?**

Thanks!

Comment: only one way to find out for sure

Comment: actually the reason I posted this question is to know if my method would work, not to find out that it doesnt

Comment: nobody can predict with 100% certainty if it will work or fail ... in the end, the only way to be sure is to do it ... your question is asking for 100% certainty ... it's a question like `will I get sick tomorrow?`